# Интерфейс Setting Telegram

Tags: android, kotlin, telegram, интерфейс, settings

[image: Screenshot приложения Telegram]

Вопрос: с помощью каких инструментов можно сделать похожий интерфейс?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ это [Preference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings). 
Для разделения экрана используется на группы (белый фон) используется [CardView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview).
Список можно создать разными способами, либо с RecyclerView, либо чуть проще с LinearLayout с ImageView + TextView или же с [Material Button](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons/), которая позволяет легко компоновать иконку и текст.
При кликах на элементы стандартный для андроида [ripple effect](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/ripple-effect-in-android/#).

Comment: спасибо, попробую